# Посоветуйте как создать мессенджер для Android - приложение и серверную части

Tags: android, messenger

Я хотел бы в качестве практики создать свой messenger.

Посмотрел различные статьи, но они все предлагали использовать Firebase для хранения данных. Посмотрев бесплатные лимиты, я понял, что это вообще только для простых.
Поэтому решил использовать свой сервер с БД, например PostgreSQL.

До этого только работал с RestFull API (писал на php, framework SLIM)

По какому принципу должен работать чат?
Например, я отправил сообщение, оно пошло на сервер (Rest, например post - Запрос), тот на Firebase Notification, и там уже другому пользователю через Notification.

А как получать обновления? Через Service дергать обновления от сервера (rest) каждые n ms?

Или это по другому как - то делается? Например общение и отправка файлов через сокеты?

К тому же не понятно, какой лучше паттерн в мобильном приложении для этих целей подойдет? MVP или MVVM?
Я просто попробовал оба, и как то все равно не определился, в каких целях использовать тот или иной паттерн.

К тому же нужно с языком определится для серверной части, думаю php будет уже проблемно использовать. А что тогда использовать лучше? Java, Kotlin или посмотреть на Go и какие Framework? Думаю лучше писать все на Kotlin, чтобы не переключаться на разные языки, но какие в нем тогда framework используют в back end - разработки?

Буду рад услышать любые советы от опытных пользователей

**P.S.** некоторые люди посоветовали использовать Hasura GraphQL Engine, получается без серверной части?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет делать свой сервер (PHP для этого не подойдёт, наверное), который сможет работать с TCP соединениями в реалтайме (не rest api).

Я в своих проектах использую [netty](https://netty.io/) (пишу на котлине) - крайне удобная и быстрая штука.

*Как происходит общение между клиентами?*

1. Пользователь запускает программу.
2. Клиент подключается к серверу (подключение держится, не разрывается).
3. Собственно далее всё общение происходит через открытый канал, пока приложение работает.
4. Когда приложение закрывается, или связь с сервером теряется - сервер переходит на использование пушей и отправляет пользователю пуш о новом сообщении. Отправляем только 1 пуш, помечаем у себя, что пользователю отправлен пуш о новых сообщениях и больше не отправляем пока он не подключится и не прочитает все сообщения. Это для экономии... Если такая задача не стоит (экономить), то, после его отключения от сервера, можно все сообщения пользователю отправлять через пуши, пока он опять не подключится.
5. А далее см. п. 1 и так по кругу.

> К тому же не понятно, какой лучше паттерн в мобильном приложении для этих целей подойдет? MVP или MVVM?

Да вообще без разницы, какой удобнее вам, тем и пользуйтесь.

Comment: а у вас открытых проектов нету, например на github, хочу посмотреть как это устроено?

Comment: @danilshik не, открытых проектов у меня нет. :(

Comment: жаль. Не подскажете насчет СУБД. В Messenger'ax в основном это операция вставки или выборки?

Просто я так подумал, если мне не нужна надежность данных, то наверно лучше использовать MongoDB (хотя до этого ее не использовал), чем PostgreSQL.

Comment: Вы писали, что если приложение закрыто, отправить 1 сообщение через Firebase. Когда пользователь снова зашел, как осуществляется актуальное состояние сообщений? вызывается rest или это через socket все делается? (до этого не работал с socket)

Comment: @danilshik 1) СУБД можете брать любую.  2) Никаких rest, забудьте о них. Всё через сокет.